# Binding the correct function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having some trouble with this website I am building. I am modifying the existing pre-loader to have a button before continuing on to the home page. The issue is I can't point the button click to the correct function for a reason that i really can't figure out. Here is the appropriate code:

Revision: Just to clarify, I'm aiming to get this button click to replicate the function performed in the final code extract: this.parent.endLoader(); but am not having any success.

The click:

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '.qLbtns', function(){
$(this).EndLoader();
});
</script>
```

The js bind:

```
$.fn.EndLoader = function(){
return this.each(function(){
    this.endLoader();
});
};
```

The function i am trying to point to:

```
QueryLoader2.prototype.endLoader = function () {
this.destroyed = true;
this.onLoadComplete();
};
```

Which is effective within this function:

```
PreloadImage.prototype.completeLoading = function () {
this.parent.imageDone++;

var percentage = (this.parent.imageDone / this.parent.imageCounter) * 100;

this.parent.overlayLoader.updatePercentage(percentage);

if (this.parent.imageDone == this.parent.imageCounter || percentage >= 100) {
    this.parent.endLoader();

}
};
```

Comment: At first EndLoader() must be $(this).EndLoader() in first statement

Comment: So, `QueryLoader2` extends every DOM elements? Or how exactly does a DOM element get the `endLoader` method?

Comment: is it normal you don't call `$(document).ready` before doing your stuff ?

Comment: @FelixKling QueryLoader2 is called at the beginning of the html document and creates DOM elements overlaying the existing, loads all images, then when done, removes itself. endLoader is called when all images are loaded. I hope I answered your question, Cheers :)

Comment: @TCHdvlp No, it's normally there. This is just an extract of the code I thought was appropriate to the question. Should I include it all next time? Sorry! Cheers :)

Comment: @Addzkebabs, it's up to you but, to be honest, it's the first thing that came to my eyes and it's a frequent mistake.

Comment: @TCHdvlp Sorry mate! I misunderstood what you said! There's no need for a $(document).ready in this scenario :) If you're still curious, I assure you it works as I've tested it with an alert.